# Como puedo devolver únicamente un archivo ical y evitar que cargue headers y mas cosas de angular

Tags: laravel, angular

Tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy desarrollando un back con laravel y consumiendo las api con Angular 12, he implementado una ruta en mi web que te descarga el archivo .ics, de tal manera que al ingresar localhost/calendar/ical, descargaría entonces el archivo (esto es para que otras plataformas puedan sincronizar los calendarios). El problema surge en que ademas de descargar el archivo,también carga archivos como runtime.js, polyfills.js,script.js, vendor.js, main.js... y yo solo quiero que al ingresar la ruta solamente descargue el archivo, sin renderizar ningun archivo del front. Esto es posible?

he intentado desde app.component.ts implementar

`ngOnInit(){

```
   if(location.pathname.include("/calendar/ical"){
     let VCALENDAR = `BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r
     PRODID:-//Events Calendar//HSHSOFT 1.0//DE\r
     CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r
     VERSION:2.0\r
     `;
     for (let event of events) {
        VCALENDAR +=
       `BEGIN:VEVENT\r
        DTSTAMP:${event.dtstamp}\r
        DTEND;VALUE=DATE:${event.end}\r
        DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:${event.start}\r
        UID:${event.uid}\r
        SUMMARY:${event.summary}\r
        END:VEVENT\r\n`;
     }
     VCALENDAR += `END:VCALENDAR`;
     const element = document.createElement('a')
     element.setAttribute('href', 
    'data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8,' + 
     encodeURIComponent(VCALENDAR))
     element.setAttribute('download', 'listing-'+list_id)
     element.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
     element.style.display = 'none'
     element.click()
    }
```

}`

Pero sigue cargando todos los archivos ya mencionados arriba como main.js, vendor.js, etc.

Comment: Todos los archivos que mencionas son los que hacen funcionar la aplicación de Angular. Si no se descargan eso que estás haciendo en el `app.component.ts` no funcionaría. Para poder descargar solo el archivo `.ics` deberías implementar un endpoint en Laravel que devuelva solo ese archivo.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, me fue de ayuda. Quería sacarme la duda si era posible limitar esas cargas de archivos